# C# Multiple Services in WCF Web.Config

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to enable multiple WCF services in my web.config file, but for some reason I'm getting the following error.

```
Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.
```

Everything looks right to me. Here is the servicemodel from web.config. I searched online and followed the methods, but strangely it's not working on my side.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfig">
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>


    <services>
      <!-- Note: the service name must match the configuration name for the service implementation. -->
      <service name="ProductDataService" behaviorConfiguration="ProductDataServiceBehavior">
        <!-- Add the following endpoint.  -->
        <!-- Note: your service must have an http base address to add this endpoint. -->
        <endpoint
            address="http://api.xxx.com/services/Product.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfig"
            contract="ProductDataService" />
        <endpoint address="mex"
            binding="mexHttpsBinding"
            contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>

      <service name="MediaContentService" behaviorConfiguration="MediaContentServiceBehavior">
        <!-- Add the following endpoint.  -->
        <!-- Note: your service must have an http base address to add this endpoint. -->
        <endpoint
            address="http://api.xxx.com/services/Media.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfig"
            contract="MediaContentService" />
        <endpoint address="mex"
            binding="mexHttpsBinding"
            contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ProductDataServiceBehavior" >
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" externalMetadataLocation="http://api.xxx.com/wsdl/ProductDataService.wsdl"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="MediaContentServiceBehavior" >
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" externalMetadataLocation="http://api.xxx.com/wsdl/MediaContentService.wsdl"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**EDIT**

Even if I just add 1 service it breaks. It only happens when adding a name for the behavior. Here is the servicemodel with just 1 service configured.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfig">
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>


    <services>
      <!-- Note: the service name must match the configuration name for the service implementation. -->
      <service name="ProductDataService" >
        <!-- Add the following endpoint.  -->
        <!-- Note: your service must have an http base address to add this endpoint. -->
        <endpoint
            address="http://api.xxx.com/services/Product.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfig"
            contract="ProductDataService" />
        <endpoint address="mex"
            binding="mexHttpsBinding"
            contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" externalMetadataLocation="http://api.xxx.com/wsdl/ProductDataService.wsdl"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: It seems when I add the behaviorConfiguration, is when it bombs

Comment: error occurred while hosting or while debugging ?

Comment: @DarshanPatel while hosting

Comment: in `endpoint` tag contract should be your interface name with namespace ex `Abc.Pqr.IXyz`

Comment: @DarshanPatel when I do that, it still breaks.  The issue is adding a behavior name. Only when I say <behavior name="ProductDataServiceBehvior"> and <service name="ProductDataService" behaviorConfiguration="ProductDataServiceBehvior" > then it complains when I access the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the full namespace to service name and full namespace to the contract, I then needed to make the endpoint address relative. Below is my full solution. For the service 'Proactive_WebAPI.Services.Media', then contract was giving an error, so removed the namespace from it and all worked fine.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfig">
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>


    <services>
      <!-- Note: the service name must match the configuration name for the service implementation. -->
      <service name="Proactive_WebAPI.Services.Product"  behaviorConfiguration="ProductDataServiceBehavior">
        <!-- Add the following endpoint.  -->
        <!-- Note: your service must have an http base address to add this endpoint. -->
        <endpoint
            address="Product.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfig"
            contract="Proactive.Product.ProductDataService" />
      </service>
      <service name="Proactive_WebAPI.Services.Media"  behaviorConfiguration="MediaContentServiceBehavior">
        <!-- Add the following endpoint.  -->
        <!-- Note: your service must have an http base address to add this endpoint. -->
        <endpoint
            address="Media.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfig"
            contract="MediaContentService" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ProductDataServiceBehavior" >
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" externalMetadataLocation="http://api.xxx.com/wsdl/ProductDataService.wsdl"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      <behavior name="MediaContentServiceBehavior" >
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" externalMetadataLocation="http://api.xxx.com/wsdl/MediaContentService.wsdl"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check service name

```
 namespace MyNameSpace
 {
   .....
    public class MyClass: IInterface
    {
```

The name= attribute on the  tag in config must be exactly what your service class is called - fully qualified, including namespace - so in your case here, it should be:

```
  <service name="MyNameSpace.MyClass" ......>
```

Also, You use mexHttp*s*Binding so use http*s*GetEnabled.  ('s' is missing in your config)

Comment: I still get the same error...when I remove the fully qualified path and also remove the behavior configurations. So just leave 1 service on. Then it works fine. As soon as I add in a name for the behavior, it complains

Comment: @Orion Also You use mexHttp*s*Binding so use http*s*GetEnabled.  ('s' is missing in your config)  or remove 's' hope it will help

Comment: it works fine with mexHttpsBinding. Just as long as I don't add a behavior name :/